# App crash when i press button with popviewcontroller

Tags: ios

I've a problem. My uiviewcontroller has button (in navigationar) with popviewcontroller. 
When i press this button without scrolling down, everything is ok. But, when i scroll down my scrollview (700px) and click on button, app crash.

Xcode show me this error: (lldb) and EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_l386_GPFLT) - nothing more.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you check IBAction connection in View?

Comment: i don't use IB. Method code is: -(void)pop
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}

Comment: Need to know how you're adding your button too, please update your question and add details.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it.. I added to -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.scroll.delegate = nil;
}
Thank you